# Error FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

When I run this activity I get error FATAL EXCEPTION, it seems to point my activity_shipper layout, to my FloatingActionButton

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shippers_man);

    fabAdd=findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
    fabAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCreateShipperLayout();
        }
    });

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_shippers);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    shippers = database.getReference(Common.SHIPPERS_TABLE);

    loadAllShippers();
}
```

I got this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fmy.frutifellesserver, PID: 19015
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fmy.frutifellesserver/com.example.fmy.frutifellesserver.ShippersMan}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.example.fmy.frutifellesserver.ShippersMan.onCreate(ShippersMan.java:44)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001(FloatingActionButton.java:69)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:862)
```

showCreateShipperLayout is a method to create an AlertDialog that let me register a new Shipper

I tried removing the floating XML button and it didn't crash.
Could it be the error?

activity_shippers_man's xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".ShippersMan">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_shippers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is `showCreateShipperLayout();` method

Comment: Post your XML code also.

Comment: please post your XML code.

Comment: Error shows that `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16` and you did not showed your xml layout?

Comment: Apologies for not showing the XML code, but the editor would not let me put a lot of code.

Comment: From the error log it seams like you are having a problem loading the @drawable and/or @color. Are you sure they both exist ?  See the last 3 lines of your log. `newDrawable()' on a null object reference` and `$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:862)`

Comment: @IgorIlic thanks, I removed "@color" and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```